# 3rd party jar which can not be put in any repository works with maven project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, maven-3

There is a 3rd party jar which is dependent by many programs on the target machine. That jar file is named as abc.jar.

I can add the jar file to the local repository as abc-1.0.jar and package my project. But that means I must manually replace abc-1.0.jar when abc.jar updates. Here are my questions:

1.Is it possible to just use abc.jar when development with Intellij IDEA? I tried add the abc.jar to the External Libraries with dependency adding. But the editor can not recognize classes within abc.jar

2.If the answer is yes, What should I do to let the war file use the system level's abc.jar not the bundled within the ear?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Find this?
[correct-way-to-add-external-jars-lib-jar-to-an-intellij-idea-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051640/correct-way-to-add-external-jars-lib-jar-to-an-intellij-idea-project)

or compile files in Gradle

```
compile files("src/main/resources/libs/sqljdbc4.jar")
```

put jar file to path

Comment: My project is managed by maven. As I described in question 1, classes in abc.jar can not be recognized by editor after I add the jar in External Libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You **can** add the abc.jar file to the particular module's dependency manually as described in [mentioned SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1051705/2000323) and you also will have to [manually add it to the artifact](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-artifacts.html#artifact_configs) which is automatically generated by IDE based on Maven configuration.

Note that the artifact configuration will be overridden on the next re-import from Maven unless you create a copy of this artifact configuration and give it another name.

Generally such approach is not recommended for Maven project. Instead you should relay on Maven configuration.

Comment: Nay. I already know what to do in the links. My issue is that it's not a solution to rename abc.jar to abc-$version.jar and put it in some repository. abc.jar must be used in Intellij IDEA and system level's abc.jar must be used on target machine not the bundled with war file